# How to delete any other user besides the currentUser with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In their docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user

And their code example:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

This only deletes my user, the one logged in. How would I look up a different user to delete based on email with Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a different user from a client web app, but you could do so from a server using the Admin SDK, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit other users using any user by implementing a code+db.

Later, using google cloud services/functions, you might be able to setup one that looks for specific values in db to delete those users for you, as it will be running as Admin.